# Which virtual machine is better to install Ubuntu with ROS? Multipass or Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, ros, multipass

I heard that people usually use VirtualBox to install Ubuntu in windows and ROS. But I wanted to know which one is better in terms of software compatibility. Is Virtualbox is better for ROS or Multipass?

Comment: Both are free. Try both, and decide which is "best" for you. Then let us know!

Answer (score 0):

Best answer is VM Ware. I was having errors in virtual box and didn't understand the interface of multipass. Don't understand Multipass interface and Hyper V worked  in beginning but having a hard time changing default settings like disk size.

VM Ware worked without any problem. Just follow this link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRl-0lcQjdU before starting any Virtual Machine tool.

Comment: so what's the difference of maas and multipass?